# Exclude a dependent file from VSS in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

I have a file, let's say `MySchema.xsd`, within a folder in a C# project.  I am auto-generating a class, `MySchema.cs`, through the use of a pre-build action that runs `xsd.exe` on it.  I can include `MySchema.cs` in my project, and VS2008 automatically makes it a dependent file of `MySchema.xsd`.

I need to include `MySchema.xsd` in source control (Visual Source Safe 2005) but exclude the generated output.  [This blog entry](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/tip-excluding-auto-generated-files-from-sourcesafe/) has a tip that does exactly what I want, except that the menu option "Exclude 'MySchema.cs' from source control" does not exist.  It seems that this menu option does not appear for dependent items.  I do have that option for `MySchema.xsd`, but that is not what I want.

I have tried temporarily making `MySchema.cs` independent by editing the `.csproj` file, then excluding the file.  That worked, but when I went to make the file dependent again, `MySchema.xsd` is also excluded.

Another solution could be just to name the output of `xsd.exe` something else, then exclude that file.  However, I would like to avoid renaming if possible.

Is there another solution I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

What about removing it from source control but still include in in the project?

Comment: Tried that too.  VS tries to re-add it to source control.  It has to be in the project so that the project will build, of course.

Comment: I know that not a req in VS 2010, don't know for older versions.